# Prove the derivative

Tags: calculus, inequality, recreational-mathematics, contest-math

Let $f(x) = (x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}, x>1$. How do I prove that the $n$th derivative of $f(x) > 0$ for odd $n$, and the $n$th derivative of $f(x) < 0$ for even $n$?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $x > 1$:
\begin{align}
\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{1/2}&=x\pars{1 - {1 \over x^{2}}}^{1/2}
=x\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \ell!\,\Gamma\pars{3/2 - \ell}}
\pars{-1}^{\ell}x^{-2\ell}
\\[3mm]&=x\pars{1 - {1 \over 2x^{2}}}
+x\sum_{\ell = 2}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \ell!\,\Gamma\pars{3/2 - \ell}}
\pars{-1}^{\ell}x^{-2\ell}
\end{align}

> However,
>   $$
> \Gamma\pars{{3 \over 2} - \ell}=
> {\pi \over \Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{\ell - 1/2}}}
> =-\pars{-1}^{\ell}\,{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2}}
> $$

$$
\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{1/2}
=x\pars{1 - {1 \over 2x^{2}}}
-{1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\sum_{\ell = 2}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2} \over \ell!}\,x^{-2\ell + 1}
$$

> \begin{align}
> \totald{\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{1/2}}{x}
> &=1 + {1 \over 2x^{2}}
> +
> {1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\sum_{\ell = 2}^{\infty}
> {\Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2} \over \ell!}\,\pars{2\ell - 1}x^{-2\ell}
> \color{#00f}{\large > 0}
> \\[3mm]
> \totald[2]{\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{1/2}}{x}
> &=-\,{1 \over x^{3}}
> -
> {1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\sum_{\ell = 2}^{\infty}
> {\Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2} \over \ell!}\pars{2\ell}\pars{2\ell - 1}x^{-2\ell - 1}
> \color{#00f}{\large < 0}
> \\[3mm]
> \totald[3]{\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{1/2}}{x}
> &={3 \over x^{4}}
> +
> {1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\sum_{\ell = 2}^{\infty}
> {\Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2} \over \ell!}\,
> \pars{2\ell + 1}\pars{2\ell}\pars{2\ell - 1}x^{-2\ell - 2}
> \color{#00f}{\large > 0}
> \\[3mm]
> \totald[4]{\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{1/2}}{x}
> &=-\,{4 \times 3 \over x^{5}}
> -
> {1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\sum_{\ell = 2}^{\infty}
> {\Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2} \over \ell!}\,
> {\pars{2\ell + 2}! \over \pars{2\ell - 2}!}x^{-2\ell - 3}
> \color{#00f}{\large < 0}
> \end{align}
>   and so on.

For $n \geq 2$ $\pars{~\mbox{for}\ n = 1\ \mbox{it's evident}~}$:
$$
\totald[n]{\pars{x^{2} - 1}^{1/2}}{x}
=\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\
\overbrace{\bracks{{n! \over 2x^{n + 1}}
+
{1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\sum_{\ell = 2}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\pars{\ell - 1/2} \over \ell!}\,
{\pars{2\ell + n - 2}! \over \pars{2\ell - 2}!}x^{-2\ell - n + 1}}}^{\ds{\large > 0}}
$$